# Oracle sql WITH clause and EXTRACT function

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to understand the difference between the 2 queries below. The second one throws syntax error. Can someone help please?

1.

```
select 
  extract(year from (sysdate - to_date('2002-12-25')) year to month) Y 
from dual;
```

2.

```
with age(d) as
(
  select (sysdate - to_date('2002-12-25')) from dual
)
select 
  extract(year from (age.d) year to month) Y 
from age;
```

error:
ORA-30083: syntax error was found in interval value expression
30083. 00000 -  "syntax error was found in interval value expression"
*Cause:    A syntax error was found during parsing an interval value

Comment: please share the message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question could be simplified a bit to, why does this work:

```
select (sysdate - date '2002-12-25') year to month from dual;

(SYSDA
------
+14-03
```

but plugging the same number produced by `sysdate - date '2002-12-25'` into the same call does not, with or without parentheses in various combinations:

```
select (5217.4197) year to month from dual;

ORA-30083: syntax error was found in interval value expression
```

The problem is that the two numbers are actually different internally. As @hinoff suggested, you can use the `dump()` function to examine them:

```
select dump(sysdate - date '2002-12-25')
from dual;

DUMP(SYSDATE-DATE'2002-12-25')
-----------------------------------
Typ=14 Len=8: 97,20,0,0,195,143,0,0

select dump(5217.4197) from dual;

DUMP(5217.4197)             
----------------------------
Typ=2 Len=5: 194,53,18,42,98
```

Type 2 is [documented](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements001.htm#SQLRF30020) as `number`. and is further explain in MoS document ID 1031902.6.

You would get the same error if you explicitly converted the calculation to a type-2 number:

```
select (cast(sysdate - date '2002-12-25' as number)) year to month from dual;

ORA-30083: syntax error was found in interval value expression
```

Type 14 seems to be an undocumented internal representation, and Oracle is able - internally - to convert that to and from an interval in a way it can't with a normal type-2 number.

You can convert a number to an interval with `numtodsinterval(5217.4197, 'DAY')`, but because the day-to-second and year-to-month intervals aren't compatible you can't extract the number of years from that (which makes some sense, as the number of days in a year varies).

You'd see similar issues if you tried to avoid it with timestamp instead of dates:

```
select (systimestamp - timestamp '2002-12-25 00:00:00') year to month from dual;

(SYSTI
------
+14-03

select dump(systimestamp - timestamp '2002-12-25 00:00:00') from dual;

DUMP(SYSTIMESTAMP-TIMESTAMP'2002-12-2500:00:00')
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Typ=190 Len=24: 97,20,0,0,9,0,0,0,38,0,0,0,44,0,0,0,24,177,20,9,10,0,0,0
```

which also isn't one of the documented interval types, but can be internally converted to either year-to-month or day-to-second. Trying to use it in your CTE also fails; using `extract(year from age.d)` gets "ORA-30076: invalid extract field for extract source" because it's seen as a DS interval at this point, and `extract(year from (age.d) year to month)` is back to ORA-30083.

You might be better off switching from intervals to other units, such as months:

```
with age(m) as
(
  select months_between(sysdate, date '2002-12-25') from dual
)
select 
  trunc(age.m / 12) Y
from age;

         Y
----------
        14
```

If you want the number of months as well you could use `trunc(remainder(age.m, 12))`.

Or if you really want an interval, convert it in the CTE:

```
with age(ym) as
(
  select numtoyminterval(
    months_between(sysdate, date '2002-12-25'), 'MONTH') from dual
)
select 
  extract(year from age.ym) Y 
from age;
```

or closer to your original:

```
with age(ym) as
(
  select (sysdate - date '2002-12-25') year to month from dual
)
select 
  extract(year from age.ym) Y 
from age;
```

Interestingly, [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/expressions009.htm) suggests this isn't really allowed - "The six combinations that yield interval values are valid in an interval expression", and date-date isn't [one of those six](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements001.htm#g196492). That might suggest type 14 is closer to an interval than a number type.

Comment: very informative. Thank you for taking the time to explain the various related bits.

Answer (score 1):

In second query there is NUMBER value `sysdate - to_date('2002-12-25')`. You cannot `EXTRACT` year from number.

In first query you convert number back to one of date interval datatype.

```
-- datatype: internal NUMBER of a DATE subtraction
SELECT dump(sysdate - to_date('2002-12-25', 'YYYY-MM-DD'))
  FROM dual;

-- datatype: INTERVAL YEAR TO MONTH 
SELECT dump((sysdate - to_date('2002-12-25', 'YYYY-MM-DD')) year to month)
  FROM dual;  

-- datatype: NUMBER
SELECT dump(extract(year from (sysdate - to_date('2002-12-25', 'YYYY-MM-DD')) year to month))
  FROM dual;
```

> DUMP returns a VARCHAR2 value containing the data type code, length in
>   bytes, and internal representation of expr.